# Can mapbox-gl group geoJSON features by value inside properties object?

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

So in leaflet I can do this:

```
const [groupedLayers] = useState<DeviceFeedLayerGroups>({
  mine: new LayerGroup(),
  public: new LayerGroup(),
  private: new LayerGroup(),
  favorite: new LayerGroup(),
});

const onEachFeature = (
  feature: Feature<Geometry, NexusGenAllTypes['GeoJSONFeatureProperties']>,
  layer: L.Layer,
  ) => {
    /* ... */
    groupedLayers[feature.properties.relation].addLayer(layer);
}

geoJSON(deviceFeed, {
  pointToLayer,
  onEachFeature,
});
```

This way I can have groups of layers that can be turned on or off. Can this be done with mapbox-gl?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't totally understand the Leaflet functionality you're talking about, but:

Mapbox GL JS doesn't support "groups" of layers. However, you could make one GeoJSON source, with several layers that display different features from it, using a filter. Then each layer can be shown or hidden independently.

Comment: Yea, it is little confusing at start because api is much different. I have managed to convert my code to mapbox-gl.